# Why can't I add route in TwinCAT 3 between two PC?

Tags: twincat, twincat-ads

I tried to set route between two computers with TwinCAT installed but I'm unable to set any connection. Computers recognize each others IP but when I try to add route nothing happens. When ADS Secure box is unchecked ADS Error 1796 - "Reading or writing not permitted" occurs.

Firewall is off. I also checked multiple possible passwords even if default pass should been blank.

Comment: The primary reason that I have seen for this is using the hostname to establish routing. If you extend the 'Advanced options' change the radio button below 'Address Info' from 'Host Name' to 'IP Address'.

Comment: I tried this as well.

Comment: "Reading or writing not permitted" upon trying to create a route means that the username and/or password is wrong. Please note that the username and password of the user logged in to the PLC are to be used. Also note that the domain must also be provided. The domain is usually the computer name. You can find the user name and domain by logging in, in to the plc, run a command shell and type SET USERDOMAIN and SET USERNAME.

Answer (score 1):

Case solved

Correct username and password were the same as the user's logged on target PC. Defoult username and password worked on real PLC but didn't work in this case that`s why I was confused.

Big thanks for help.